# Fabric.js accessing to group in a function

Tags: fabricjs

Hello guy and thanks so much for your help.

I am a newbie in [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and I have a basic question.

1. I create a group of 3 objects in a function.
2. I want to change property of an object of this group in another function.

And more generally it will be really useful if someone can explain to me how to access to another object of a group?

I don't know how to do that.

```
function groupit() //Works {
  var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    fill: 'red',
    left: 0
  });
  var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    left: 100
  });
  var circle3 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    left: 200
  });
  var group = new fabric.Group([ circle1, circle2, circle3 ], {
    left: 200,
    top: 100
  });
  canvas.add(group);
}

function groupchg() //Does not work {
  canvas.setActiveGroup(group);
  group.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `canvas.setActiveGroup(group);` in your `function groupchg()`, and property `group` is probably null. Can fix if define `group` property out of `function groupit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found solution.

To access to specific object of a group i use this code :

```
function groupchg() {

//console.log(canvas.getActiveGroup());
canvas.setActiveObject(canvas._objects[0]._objects[1]);
var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
activeObj.setFill('red');
activeObj.set({left: 30,top:150});
canvas.renderAll();
}
```